# Change ion-view header color in ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am using the ionic starter menubar template. I would like to change the header background color of each page. I currently have:

```
<ion-view view-title="Search">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Search</h1>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I tried:

```
<ion-view view-title="Search" class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Search</h1>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

But it does not work at all (content is not rendered). The [header documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#header) does not help me. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Did you change the class in `ion-nav-bar` tag located in the `index.html ` file? ex. `<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">`

Comment: I am trying to have a different color for each page, not the same color for every page.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Some ways to do this:

1. You could add the ion-nav-bar to each view.

   ```
   <ion-view view-title="Page 1">
     <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
       <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
     </ion-nav-bar>
     <ion-content>
       ...
     </ion-content>
   </ion-view>
   ```

   [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/brandyshea/pen/NqxLzG?editors=101)
2. You could also update the background-color (and any other properties) by using ng-style

   Main navbar:

   ```
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" ng-style="{'background-color': viewColor}">
       <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
     </ion-nav-bar>
   ```

   CSS:

   ```
   .nav-bar-block, .bar {
     background-color: inherit !important;
   }
   ```

   Controller:

   ```
   $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {
       $rootScope.viewColor = 'green';
   });
   ```

   [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/brandyshea/pen/ZGQmYP)

Comment: You would have to add the menu button to each ion-nav-bar because you are redefining the navigation bar for each view.

Comment: @NiravGandhi in order to see the menu button you can use the following snippet:

<ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-back-button>

<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
</button>
</ion-nav-buttons>

Answer (score 3):

Could not find a clean solution for this, but one hack might be to use the `$stateChangeStart` event and set the class name manually.

```
angular.module('starter')
.run(function ($rootScope) {
    var element;
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
        if (next.name) {
            element = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('ion-header-bar'));
            switch(next.name) {
                case 'tab.chats':
                    element.removeClass('bar-positive');
                    element.removeClass('bar-balanced');
                    element.addClass('bar-calm');
                    break;
                case 'tab.dash':
                    element.removeClass('bar-calm');
                    element.removeClass('bar-balanced');
                    element.addClass('bar-positive');
                    break;
                default :
                    element.removeClass('bar-calm');
                    element.removeClass('bar-positive');
                    element.addClass('bar-balanced');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5zt2y1p/1/)

**EDIT**
The idea is same for sidebar template,

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hd94q3y/1/)

Notice the line

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
```

in menu.html template, it denotes the base header color class.
but subsequent changes to pages i.e states header color needs to be changed manually in `$stateChangeStart` event,

code:

```
.run(function ($rootScope) {
    var element;
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
        if (next.name) {
            element = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('ion-side-menu-content ion-header-bar'));
            console.log(element);
            switch(next.name) {
                case 'app.search':
                    element.removeClass('bar-positive');
                    element.removeClass('bar-energized');
                    element.removeClass('bar-dark');
                    element.addClass('bar-assertive');
                    break;
                case 'app.browse':
                    element.removeClass('bar-calm');
                    element.removeClass('bar-assertive');
                    element.removeClass('bar-dark');
                    element.addClass('bar-energized');
                    break;
                default :
                    element.removeClass('bar-positive');
                    element.removeClass('bar-energized');
                    element.removeClass('bar-assertive');
                    element.addClass('bar-dark');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

1. here the state name is checked to see which page is activating ex. `app.search`
2. then according to requirement specific color class is assigned removing other color classes.

[ionic color options](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#header)

hope this helps.

Comment: I am using the menubar template and not the tab template. I do not care to set a class on each view directly in the html. However, where should I set the class?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using different states and each state has a different controller than just have a $scope variable like `$scope.stateone = "true"` etc. Then on your ion-nav-bar use `ng-class="{'bar-positive': stateone, 'bar-stable': statetwo, 'bar-assertive': statethree}"`. ng-class takes classes and an expression, whichever expression is true that is the class that is assigned. you can use ng-class with any boolean expression. this is how you can have a different color on each page.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for ion-nav-bar as the child ion-header-bar does not update with the parent class.

Comment: Ah i see, that is unforntunate.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the solution of @shakib to fit my needs, in my case the user sets the theme by clicking the app logo and thus the bar color should change. If this is your case you don't need to do the `switch case` because you want to change all views

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState) {
          var element;
          if (toState.name){
              element = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('ion-side-menu-content ion-header-bar'));
              if (debugMode) console.log(element);
              // I get the bar-class from my localStorage where I keep the user settings
              var saved_bar_class = $localStorage.get('bar-class','bar-calm');

              element.removeClass('bar-pink');
              element.removeClass('bar-calm');
              element.addClass(saved_bar_class);
          //    Here We could use a Switch Case on toState.name to put a different color to each state

          }
      });
```

Also when the user clicks the app logo I want to immediately change the bar color in order to give feedback to the user of what that button do. The above code won't do that because we haven't changed state yet, to fix this just add this code to your 'change theme' function

```
$scope.changeAppTheme = function () {
        var element;
        element = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('ion-side-menu-content ion-header-bar'));
            // some code to select the theme
            element.removeClass('bar-pink');
            element.removeClass('bar-calm');
            element.addClass('bar-pink');
            // some other code
    };
```

In this case I just have two colors, the ionic calm and a pink one that I defined 
Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

We got it working in CSS with:

```
.title.title-center.header-item {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

This means that we just refer to the Angular generated header classes directly with this CSS. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
    <h1 class="title">Search</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Search</h1>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Your code gives an empty header with no specific color (grey).

Answer (score 0):

You can override `$bar-stable-text color` (taken from `_variables.scss` from `ionic lib`)

For example, in your scss change

```
$bar-stable-text: green !default;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the `ion-nav-bar` this here works like a charm:

1 . Create a main controller to take care of your index page and all views within it.
2. Add this function to the controller:

```
$scope.setNavColor = function(color){
    for(var i =0; i <  document.getElementsByTagName("ion-header-bar").length; i++){
      classNames = document.getElementsByTagName("ion-header-bar")[i].className;
      classNames = classNames.replace(/(bar-light|bar-stable|bar-positive|bar-calm|bar-balanced|bar-energized|bar-assertive|bar-royal|bar-dark)/g, color );
      document.getElementsByTagName("ion-header-bar")[i].className = classNames;
    }
  }
```

3 . add on-select to your `ion-tab` tab so it will call the function whenever your tab is chosen:
`<ion-tab href="#addr" on-select="setNavColor('PUT_YOUR_COLOR_HERE')> </ion-tab>`

4 . add on-deselect to you `ion-tab` too if you want the color to go back to some value when you leave.

5 . Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

put these lines in your style.css under `/www/css/` directory of your ionic project

```
.title.title-center.header-item {
    background-color:#4a87ee;//#F38023!important; // for bg color
    margin:0px!important;
    margin-left:0px!important;
    color: #ffffff!important;
    text-align: center !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//add these lines in your style.css file under /www/css/ yoyr project    directory
 .title.title-center.header-item {
    background-color:#30393A;//#F38023!important; // for bg color
    margin:0px!important;
    margin-left:0px!important;
    color: #ffffff!important;
    text-align: center !important;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using scss within your app, you can create your own custom bar class and use ionic's bar mixins in it.

```
$bar-custom-bg: #ccc;
$bar-custom-border: #eee;
$bar-custom-text: #fff;
$bar-custom-active-border: darken($bar-custom-border, 10%);
$bar-custom-active-bg: darken($bar-custom-bg, 10%);

.bar {
    &.bar-custom {
        @include bar-style($bar-custom-bg, $bar-custom-border, $bar-custom-text);
        &.bar-footer{
            background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, $bar-custom-border, $bar-custom-border 50%, transparent 50%);
        }

        .button {
            @include button-style($bar-custom-bg, $bar-custom-border, $bar-custom-active-bg, $bar-custom-active-border, $bar-custom-text);
            @include button-clear(#fff, $bar-title-font-size);
        }
    }
}
```

After defining your class, you can use your new custom bar class with ion-nav-bar directive.

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-custom">
    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```